# Multithreading, blocking and memory mapped files

Tags: linux, multithreading, memory-mapped-files

In a multi-threaded process with a memory-mapped file, what happens if one thread dereferences a page not yet in memory? Does the OS block the whole process or just that thread? What about other OSs? (BSD, OSX, Windows)

Edit: [interesting report](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0905.0/00338.html) on lkml 2009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing an address not mapped into the process's virtual address space causes a hardware exception called a *page fault*. This will block the *operating system thread* until the exception is dealt with. This is the standard mode of operation for all OSes that support virtual memory.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. For the curious, found this making it a bit more clear http://www.scs.stanford.edu/08wi-cs240/notes/scheduler_activations.txt